# sort list of tuples by reordering tuples

Tags: python, performance, sorting, tuples

Given a list of tuples to sort, python will sort them according to first element in tuple, then 
second element and so on.

```
>>> A
[(3, 2, 1), (0, 3, 0), (2, 1, 0), (2, 2, 3), (0, 3, 2), (2, 1, 1), (3, 3, 2), (3, 2, 0)]
>>> sorted(A)
[(0, 3, 0), (0, 3, 2), (2, 1, 0), (2, 1, 1), (2, 2, 3), (3, 2, 0), (3, 2, 1), (3, 3, 2)]
```

This works great.
Now I want to sort them by third element, then first element and then the second element which I can do by either providing a key function or a cmp function.

```
>>> A
[(3, 2, 1), (0, 3, 0), (2, 1, 0), (2, 2, 3), (0, 3, 2), (2, 1, 1), (3, 3, 2), (3, 2, 0)]
>>> sorted(A, key = lambda x: (x[2], x[0], x[1]))
[(0, 3, 0), (2, 1, 0), (3, 2, 0), (2, 1, 1), (3, 2, 1), (0, 3, 2), (3, 3, 2), (2, 2, 3)]
```

except i take a major performance penalty

```
s ="""\
from numpy.random import randint as rr
A=[tuple(rr(0,10,3)) for i in range(100)]
def tuplecmp(t1, t2):
    return t1[0] - t2[0]
"""
c1 = """\
sorted(A)
"""
c2 = """\
sorted(A, key=lambda x: (x[2], x[0], x[1]))
"""
c3 = """\
sorted(A, cmp = tuplecmp)
"""
import timeit
print timeit.timeit(c1,number=10000, setup= s)
print timeit.timeit(c2,number=10000, setup= s)
print timeit.timeit(c3,number=10000, setup= s)
```

giving

```
0.60133600235,
0.980231046677,
2.68837809563
```

Further, the order in which I compare the individual tuple elements need not remain same. I may need to compare by 'second, first, then third' element etc. 
Is there a better method to do provide arbitrary comparator functions without a major performance penalty;

Comment: Is `0.38` really that much of a penalty?

Comment: This is a toy example, my actual application sorts all the pixels in a 3 or 6 channel image by their intensities for each channel. Frequently i have millions of pixels per image, and few tens of images. I am also looking into a custom bucket sort implementation since each channel's value is between 0-255.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `operator.itemgetter` for your `key` function may be faster; you'd have to try it.

```
import operator
sorted(A, key=operator.itemgetter(2, 0, 1))
```

Comment: operator.itemgetter is indeed faster. 0.814254999161 seconds precisely for same amount of work.  Also works better for my application than lambdas since i can just provide a different order of comparison directly in the itemgetter arguments. thnx!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a better way to do what you're trying to do. I believe you're always going to have to supply your own comparator, and then pay the cost of calling that over and over again.